# First term of a series with two zeros and a constant second difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

> For any sequence of real numbers $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\dots\}$, define $ΔA$ to be the sequence $\{a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2,a_4-a_3,\dots\}$ whose $n$th term is $a_{n+1}-a_n$. Suppose that all of the terms of the sequence $Δ(ΔA)$ are 1, and that $a_{19}=a_{94}=0$. Find $a_1$.

I'm seeing that the first series must be $\{1,2,4,7,\dots\}$ which is strictly increasing, but the series has two zeros.

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: yeh, used some nth term tried to manipulate it didnt get far, then worked that the first series must be like this; 1, 2,4,7..., but if it is like that i dont understand how a19 and a94 can be zero, as the first series must be increasing?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\Delta(\Delta A)=\{1,1,1,\dots\}$$
$$\Delta A=\{b,b+1,b+2,\dots\}$$
$$A=\{c,c+b,c+2b+1,c+3b+3,\dots\}$$
For a fixed $b$ and $c$ we have
$$a_n=c+(n-1)b+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}2$$
The condition that $a_{19}=a_{94}=0$ translates to
$$a_{19}=c+18b+153=0$$
$$a_{94}=c+93b+4278=0$$
Subtract the first equation from the second:
$$75b+4125=0;\ b=-55$$
$$c=-153-18b=-153-18(-55)=837$$
Hence $a_1=c=837$.

Comment: how did you work out that nth term is (n-1)(n-2)/2?, i know its easy to work out from looking at the sequence 1,3,6,10... but is there a more systematic approach?

Comment: @grigori In $\Delta A$ the constant part of the expression (after the $b$) goes 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. Hence the constant part in $A$ must go 0, 0+0, 0+0+1, 0+1+2 and so on, and the constant in $a_n$ is the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to $n-2$. A formal derivation of the triangular numbers formula can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).